# Sharepoint Document Template Quick Parts?

Tags: document, template, quick-parts

My objective is to create some custom document templates that are connected to list data. At first glance I thought this would be pretty straight forward using quick parts but I have run into a snag that has me scratching my head.. One of the requested behaviors is to have sub criteria / options auto populate.

I am not sure quite how to approach this. or if its even possible with a document template.

Scenario:
User selects "**Company**" from a drop down
The address information auto populates (Address, State , Zip)
If multiple addresses are present in the list for the company the fields remain blank and the first address options are limited to the addresses associated with the "**Company**"

The same behavior has been requested for adding contacts and so on.

Does anyone have some suggestions on how best to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

[This article covers it off](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/quick-tip-combining-word-and-metadata-through-quick-parts).

I have found sometimes when I go insert, quick part, the meta data I have selected in my content type is not present. If I remove and re-attach the content type, this usually fixes it.

I have also seen that I need to "edit template" in the parent content type to access these options, if that makes sense.

Comment: The question doesn't seem very clear. Please provide more information to get the best answers.